# Magento Update Multiselect Attribute: add 1 option (dont overwrite curent0) via script or massupdate or extension

Tags: magento-1, product-attribute, multiselect-attribute

Magento Update Multiselect Attribute: add 1 option (dont overwrite curent0) via script or massupdate or extension

Situation
Product with multiselect attribute for color

```
 - COLOR       [Green]   [Yellow]    [Blue]    [Red]        
 - Product1       x         x          x         
 - Product2                            x          
 - Product3                 x
```

We now want to update all 3 products in 1 go to be like this

```
 - COLOR       [Green]   [Yellow]    [Blue]    [Red]        
 - Product1       x         x          x         x
 - Product2                            x         x
 - Product3                 x                    x
```

In this case we ADD the option RED to all 3 (and dont remove any data)

Questions:
Can this be done via a massupdate in backend? (I think it overwrites all and leaves ONLY red selected); or maybe via a script or other method?

I appreciate your help

Comment: Would this be for Magento 1 or 2?

Comment: 1. But maybe als 2 for others. We use m1

Comment: Can you please give soe feedback if it works for you?

Answer (score 1):

I think mass action will overwrite current values.

To update a multiselect attribute you have to save the options IDs as comma seperated string ...

For multiple products this should work:

```
$attributeCode = 'multiselect_attribute';
$attributeValue = 'Red';
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attributeCode);
$optionId = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionId($attributeValue);

$productIds = array(1, 2);
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addIdFilter($productIds)
    ->addAttributeToSelect($attributeCode);

$storeId = 0;
$action = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_action');
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $options = array_filter(explode(',', $product->getData($attributeCode)));
    $options[] = $optionId;
    $options = array_unique($options);
    $action->updateAttributes(
        array($product->getId()),
        array($attributeCode => implode(',', $options)),
        $storeId
    );
}
```

**Note:** after that you have to reindex your attributes manually

Comment: Perhaps you should add a call to `array_unique` just to prevent dups?

Comment: Also be aware, this snippet does not add an indexer event like the normal mass action code does.

Comment: @LeeSaferite it works without `array_unique`, but its definitly cleaner. Also added `array_filter` to prevent empty array value (`explode(',', null)`). Thanks for mention indexer ... i'll add some code later :)

Comment: thanks see my answer below. We use rawdata() .... but this code looks like it does exactly what it needs to do. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution we are using now, where data is offered using a product id and a column header. Of the header code is multiselect then it executes the code utilizing - and + to add or remove data from the multiselect.

```

```
                $attribute = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getResource()->getAttribute($_key);
                if (
                    $attribute->getFrontendInput() === 'multiselect'
                    && $attribute->getBackend() instanceof Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Array
                ) {
                    /**
                     * Handles multiselect attribute
                     */
                    $toAdd = array();
                    $toSubstract = array();

                    foreach (explode('|', $_keyval) as $singleKeyValue) {
                        // Parse & check operator
                        $operator = substr($singleKeyValue, 0, 1);
                        if (!in_array($operator, array("-","+"))) {
                            Mage::throwException('Unallowable operator: '.$operator);
                        }

                        // get option value id
                        $optionValue = substr($singleKeyValue, 1);
                        $optionValueId = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionId($optionValue);

                        if (!$optionValueId) {
                            Mage::throwException('No such option');
                        }

                        if ($operator === "+") {
                            $toAdd[] = $optionValueId;
                        } else {
                            // is "-"
                            $toSubstract[] = $optionValueId;
                        }
                    }
                    // get current product value ids
                    $currentValue = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue($_id, $_key, Mage::app()->getStore());
                    $currentOptionValues = explode(',', $currentValue);
                    sort($currentOptionValues);

                    $newOptionValues = array_diff($currentOptionValues, $toSubstract);
                    $newOptionValues = array_merge($newOptionValues, $toAdd);
                    $newOptionValues = array_unique($newOptionValues);
                    sort($newOptionValues);

                    if ($newOptionValues !== $currentOptionValues) {
                        $valuesToSave[$_key] = implode(',', $newOptionValues);
                    }
                }
                    /**
                     * Saving prepared values to the product
                     * in one transaction
                     */
                    Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(array($id), $valuesToSave, 0);
```

```